# PHP what to do when records don't exist in the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I'm querying the database for a single record that matches the id passed in a url segment `www.site.com/post/24`.

Suppose post `24` doesn't exist. What is a safe and *seo compliant* way to deal with database requests that aren't found?

Below is my current solution using a Codeigniter model:

```
    function read_post($post_id) //argument is the value of the url segment
    {
        $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get('posts');

        //check if record exists
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) //row is returned
        {
            return $query->row(); //passed to controller and view
        }
        else
        {
            show_404(); //generate 404 message
            return FALSE; //------------------------or exit()?
        }
    }
```

Please share your own best method/opinions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show a 404 page (with the 404 HTTP status code). That's the correct way of doing it. Otherwise you will just pretend you have infinitely many pages without content.

Describe shortly on the 404 page that the content isn't there anymore. Then you may add links to other popular content on your web page. For the sake of the user it's encouraged to try to lead them forward *from* the 404 page *to* interesting content, but do this with links so the user can read the 404 message and choose what to do next.

If you have meaningful URLs with words in you may also extract the words and do some kind of search in your database. List the search results on the 404 page as well, under some heading like "You may be interested in...". If you are selling a product or service, don't hesitate to make the 404 page into a nice selling one!

I have a strong belief in that the best SEO is the one which is best for your visitors. It's all about *keeping them* on your web site, and not scaring them away. Make your web site as user-friendly as possible and make it easy to find all your interesting content. My answer above stems directly from that belief. Do The Right Thing according to the standards (the HTTP standard in this case) and at the same time try to catch the user with good content and services. This is most certainly also what's best for your company at large regarding sales.

Comment: Thank you for the great advice! I noticed a lot of websites doing that

Answer (score 2):

SEO has nothing to do with your database.

SEO has to do with keywords, titles, descriptions, word frequency, outgoing links to pages in the same teritory as the article on the final rendered HTML document.

Also, you need SEO friendly links such as `/beach-party-on-sunday/`, `/post/24` won't cut it.

Answer:
According to SEO sanity, and HTTP servers workings in general, if an URL does not exist at your website **it is best to respond with a 404 HTTP status**, instead of 200 success.
However, if you have an URL for which you wish to redirect users, use permament or temporary redirects depending on wether the URL will come back to life or not.

Just play it simple and to the rules, and you will be SEO friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I redirect to the homepage. In this specific case, I would redirect to www.site.com/post.

Comment: This is often confusing. If there was a /post/24 earlier and the user got there through a link from somewhere, what good does it make her that they land on /post?

Comment: At least she can see the other posts. There is nothing to save her from a missing page.

Comment: @jarchuleta, yes I agree but for public posts I think it's good to let search engines (that might have indexed the post) know that the post doesn't exist anymore (using a 404 message or whichever message deals with that...)